# Symfony2 prevent logout on main page

Tags: symfony, firewall

In my Symfony2 project, I want only secured access to any URL under the /user pattern; while the index page (/) and a few other pages (eg. /about ) should be available without signing in. And all this works fine currently.
However, after a user has logged in, if he visits the index page, or the about page, he gets signed out! How do I prevent this from happening?

I tried adding a `security: false`, as well as an `anonymous: ~` firewall rule for the "/" and "/about" patterns, after the 'secured area' rule for the "/user" pattern. But it still doesn't work.

The answer given to the following question is probably very close to what I want: [symfony 2: get current logged in user on non secured pages through firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363674/symfony-2-get-current-logged-in-user-on-non-secured-pages-through-firewall) . The only thing missing from that answer is: how to redirect any '/user' URL to the login page, upon being denied by access control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well, got the answer myself, after a bit more tries. 
The key was to encompass the whole app with a firewall rule for the `^/` pattern, that contains an `anonymous: ~` as well as a `form_login` block.